# How to pass Data to a ViewController created using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've created an app that uses a bunch load of Container views. Today i've found out that embedded segues are not supported in iOS 5 (thanks Xcode for letting me know.)
So right now I have a lot of embedded segues that passes data between one another.

I'm using this code to load ViewControllers inside a UIView instead of the Container from the IB:

**RootViewController:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    NewsViewController *news = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewsViewControllerID"];
    news.view.frame = self.newsSection.bounds;
    [self.newsSection addSubview:news.view];
    [self addChildViewController:news];
    [news didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

How can I use the above and still pass data to NewsViewController (something like prepare for segue)

I've tried inserting in the above something like

```
        NewsViewController *news = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewsViewControllerID"];
        news.view.frame = self.newsSection.bounds;
        news.myLabel.text = @"Test";
        [self.newsSection addSubview:news.view];
```

But the label won't change.

I prefer just to pass the data and not use a singleton or delegation.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend creating a public method, from where you could pass the data you need on your `NewsViewController` controller. Still, the issue right now is that the you are updating the UI before it has been initialised. Also I would recommend you to have a look on how to create content `UIViewControllers`, because right now you are only adding its `UIView`. Check [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers/CreatingCustomContainerViewControllers.html) document from Apple, look at the section *Implementing a Custom Container View Controller*. And this part of the code:

```
- (void) displayContentController: (UIViewController*) content;
{
   [self addChildViewController:content];                 // 1
   content.view.frame = [self frameForContentController]; // 2
   [self.view addSubview:self.currentClientView];
   [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];          // 3
}
```

So in your case, after the step 3 has been made, you could pass the values you want to use inside your `NewsViewController`.

Comment: Thanks for your working detailed answer. I'm using Containers all over my app. What makes you say that I'm adding only UIView? In the code above i'm adding UIViewControllers to my UIViews. That's what Containers are all about right?

Comment: I did saw you used `addChildViewController`but not the `didMoveToParentViewController`which is necessary. From the documentation: `If you are implementing your own container view controller, it must call the didMoveToParentViewController: method of the child view controller after the transition to the new controller is complete or, if there is no transition, immediately after calling the addChildViewController: method.`

Comment: You can have unexpectable problems, for example with rotations.

Comment: unexpectable problems - No Thanks! I've added that line in the code. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be that at the moment you are setting the text of the label, the label is still `nil`.

Try adding an `NSString` `property` to your `NewsViewController` (e.g. labelText), and in `viewDidLoad` do `self.myLabel.text = self.labelText;`.

Comment: I'm not following. I want to pass data to self.labelText, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

you have pass the string your next view controller and viewDidLoad you have to the string.
Its not working because your view not yet created and if check the instance of UIlabel it will nil. So you have set the text in your next viewcontroller when it loaded in the memory.

**Edit**
you have create a property variable of NSString type(textString) in NewsViewController and pass the string as `news.textString = @"Test";`

and the in ViewDidLoad of NewsViewController set that string to label as myLabel.text = textString;

**Better Explanation**

-Declare NSString property in the NewsViewController.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *assignText;
```

-Instantiate normally, but assign the string and not the label.

```
UIStoryboard* storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
    NewsViewController *news = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NewsViewControllerID"];
    news.assignText = @"Test";
    [self addChildViewController:news];
```

-Then in your NewsViewController viewDidload, assign the label to the string.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];
  self.myLabel.text = self.assignText;
}
```

Comment: I know that I have to pass it. How do I pass it?

Comment: can I know the reason of -ve voting?